# Command to switch between bluetooth speaker profiles

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I have this problem [After pause no sound with UE Boom bluetooth speaker on Macbook](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/711201/341192) that I can fix by re-connecting the speaker (disconnecting and reconnecting). I can even do that with one command like this

```
bluetoothctl disconnect C0:28:8D:81:64:5A && bluetoothctl connect C0:28:8D:81:64:5A
```

But that takes 2-3 seconds and makes a specific connect/disconnect couple of booming sounds in the speaker.

On the other hand, changing from a "high fidelity" profile to a "headset" one in `pavucontrol`, and then back, fixes the problem without any such booming sound:

[image]

Can a such switch of profile be done by CLI command? That would be instantaneous amd without "booming"...

I was looking [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1415194/925128).

```
pactl list cards short
803     alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0.3    alsa
804     alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0.3    alsa
9178    bluez_card.C0_28_8D_81_64_5A    module-bluez5-device.c
```

but

```
pacmd
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
```

Also:

```
pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 9222
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: cip
Host Name: cip-MacBookAir
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.65)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: bluez_output.C0_28_8D_81_64_5A.1
Default Source: bluez_input.C0_28_8D_81_64_5A.0
Cookie: 3862:926e
```

Comment: Anything you can do using pavucontrol can be done using pacmd, but getting the sinks and outputs right can be a pain

Comment: @muru - I've tried to test `pacmd`, but I get `No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.`

Comment: Are you using Pipewire?

Comment: @muru - I think so. `pactl info` ... `Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.65)`